# Maven Ant 2.1.3 dependencies task does not work with type filter

Tags: ant, maven

I am using Maven Ant Tasks library to automatically resolve dependencies. I am trying to use "type" filter in "dependencies" task. Task works only if I do not add "type" filter. Even default value "jar" does not resolve any dependency. Removing type filter selects all dependencies which is around 50, but I need just 4. I specifically want "ejb-client" dependencies selected. It works if I manually specify my dependencies. Below is two set of codes. First one does not work when I add "type", second one works. Can anyone help me resolve this.

```
    <artifact:dependencies filesetId="dependency.war.lib.fileset" pomRefId="war" type="jar"/>

    <artifact:dependencies filesetId="dependency.war.lib.fileset">
        <dependency groupId="xxxx" artifactId="xxx" version="1.0.0" type="ejb-client" />
    </artifact:dependencies>
```

Comment: Let's assume your pom has packaging war, then specify `type="war,jar"` and it would work. Don't ask me for the reason, I had the same problem. I consider this a bug in maven ant tasks. See [MANTTASKS-41](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MANTTASKS-41) and [MANTTASKS-149](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MANTTASKS-41).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing file-type and `packaging` type of the POM ( that's the value referred by the `type` attribute ).

Here is what [POM reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) has to say about dependency type:

> Corresponds to the dependant artifact's packaging type. This defaults
>   to jar. While it usually represents the extension on the filename of
>   the dependency, that is not always the case. A type can be mapped to a
>   different extension and a classifier. The type often corresponds to
>   the packaging used, though this is also not always the case. Some
>   examples are jar, ejb-client and test-jar. New types can be defined by
>   plugins that set extensions to true, so this is not a complete list.

I speculate, that because `pomRefId` on your first line has a value of `war`, the valid value for `type` would be `war` and not `jar`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand what "type" stands for in dependency. Maven Ant lib indicates that default type filter value is "jar". I do have "jar" packaging types (that includes third party jar files) in the path which also do not get selected as soon as I add type filter.

Comment: @Senthil. Can you include the `<pom>` that you reference with `pomRefId`?  I think because that pom is of `war` type it gets rejected out of hand and its dependencies are not processed at all.  I suggest that you drop the `type` parameter, copy the resulting fileset to your build directory and then filter required resources using Ant's `<fileset>`

Comment: Thanks. That was my fallback option.